# Lazy Fetching doesn't work with many to one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a class `A` has one to many relationship with `B`, when I want to fetch `B` I don't want to fetch `A`, which means that I want a lazy fetching, In this case my code looks like this (didn't write the setter and getter methods)

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@Entity
public class B{

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
  private A a;
}


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@Entity
public class A  {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<B> bs;
}
```

The problem is that I am given an infinite recursion, where B contains A and A contains Bs and so on, I tried to use `@JsonBackReference()` at `ManyToOne` and `@JsonManagedReference()` at `OneToMany` and this solved the recursion issue but the fetching is still `EAGER` not `LAZY`. Also, I don't want to use `@JsonIgnore` since my point is not sending another query to fetch `A`.

Comment: How did you check that fetching is still done eagerly? Lazy fetching should work with `ManyToOne` (although the `ToOne` relations are eager by default) - are you sure you don't see a N+1 select instead? If not, can you show us the query you're using?

Comment: I guess the objects are serialized by reflexion, by using getters. That's why the objects are always fetched. Maybe you could create an intermediate model which contains values from entities (and omit lazy attributes), and then you serialize in JSON.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I am seeing N+1 Select! I thought that this is an eager fetching

Comment: No that is lazy fetching which means the reference to `A` is fetched when you access it (which Jackson most certainly is doing).

Comment: @Thomas is the Eager fetching executed in one query? Also, how to avoid Jackson from doing this? (and why it is doing this anyway!)

Comment: Eager fetching would mean one query, yes. If Jackson is meant to serialize an instance of `B` and add `a` to the JSON it _will have_ to check for the value of `a` and then try to serizalize it. And since you have a bidirectional reference (at least Jackson sees it that way because is _could_ be that one `A` contains a `B` that references the very same `A` again) Jackson will complain about a potential endless loop. - I'm no Jackson expert but the only way to solve that might be to provide a custom serializer (and maybe a deserializer).

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this? And would this happen when using Hibernate's default serializer?